# Jest Enzyme Test for A Component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a loader component

```
import React from 'react'
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import logo from '../../assets/images/hydra_eco_logo.png'

const styles = theme => ({
    image: {
        position: "absolute",
        top: "50%",
        left: "50%",
        width: "120px",
        height: "120px",
        margin: `-60px 0 0 -60px`,
        animation:`spin 4s linear infinite`,
        borderRadius: `30%`
    },
    "@keyframes spin" : { 
        "100%" : { 
            transform: "rotate(360deg)" 
        } 
    }
});



const Loader = (props) => {
    const classes = props.classes
    return(
        <div className={classes.loader}>
            <img className={classes.image} src={logo} alt="Loader Image"  />
        </div>
    )
}


export default withStyles(styles)(Loader);
```

so I want to test if the Loader is rendered or not and the loader image is loaded or not
my test file looks like this

```
import React from 'react';
import '../../../setupTests'
import { shallow} from 'enzyme';
import Loader from './Loader';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import logo from '../../assets/images/hydra_eco_logo.png';


describe('<Loader />', () => {
    it('should render without throwing an error', function() {
        expect(shallow(<Loader />).find('div img').prop("src")).toEqual(logo);
    });

    it('match src of loader image', function() {
        const wrapper = shallow(<Loader />);
        const image = wrapper.find('div img')
        expect(image).toBeTruthy();
        expect(image.prop("src")).toEqual(logo); 
    });
})
```

It throws error `Method “props” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.`
I tried resolving it, it comes out it cannot be used for nested elements such as I have img under div, since I am new to testing and React I need help ! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try using `mount` instead of `shallow`:

```
import { mount} from 'enzyme';
...
const wrapper = mount(<Loader />);
```

I'd also change the following:

```
expect(image).toBeTruthy();
```

To something like:

```
expect(image.length).toEqual(1);
```

Comment: I want to check if src of image is valid! Your answer doesn't tells this.

Comment: You are getting the error `Method “props” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.` because `image` has not been rendered because of the `shallow` render instead of `mount` (`shallow` does not render children)